# How to display contents of a file with formatting preserved on the browser using Perl CGI

Tags: html, perl, formatting, cgi

I have a text file saved in the server side. I have to read the file and display its content to the browser using perl CGI. The file has several paragraphs,  newline and tab characters. I want to preserve those formatting. Currently the contents of the file is displayed, but it is all jumbled up as a single continuous paragraph.

```
print "<table border='1'>\n";
    print "<tr>\n";
    print "<td><b>Whole Report</b></td>\n";
    print "</tr>\n";
    print "<tr>\n";
    print "<td>$entireReport</td>\n";
    print "</tr>\n";
    print "</table>\n";
```

In the above code, I am reading the entire content of the file into the variable $entireReport.

Thanks

Comment: The simple option is to use `<pre></pre>` with the usual escaping. Otherwise, you'll need to identify paragraphs and indents and recreate them with HTML/CSS.

Comment: Thanks ikegami, It worked like a charm!! Thanks a lot!! But I don't see a place to accept this as the answer.

Comment: There could be an existing [module](http://search.cpan.org/) to do that. I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap the code in a <PRE></PRE> tag. Say you have the contents in $fileContents then use:

```
print "<td><pre>", CGI::escapeHTML($fileContents), "</pre></td>\n";
```

This will keep the formatting in the file verbatim.

--dmg